# How does one implement background app refresh in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am new at Programing and to Swift. I understand the basic syntax and how to do all the common things from reading Apple's "The Swift Programming Language". But I cannot find any good documentation with examples and beginner explanations on implementing iOS Background app refresh. I have tried many Swift tutorial websites, I've turned to Google, and even searched through Apple's own web documentation, and have so far haven't had success. How does one go about implementing Background app refresh in an iOS app (using Swift)?

Comment: You may find the StackOverflow's [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/topics) very handy. If you want to lear the basics, grab a book or attend the online Stanford course on iTunes U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of learner you are. There are plenty of valuable resources I can recommend you. To mention a few:

- [Swift Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013461061X)

A book that contains well explained Swift concepts where authors reinforce what you learned throughout practice and challenges at the end of each chapter. Highly recommended.

- [Swift 3 Essential Training: The Basics](https://www.lynda.com/Swift-tutorials/Swift-3-Essential-Training-Basics/517449-2.html)

A course from [Lynda.com](http://lynda.com) with high reputation in which they explain professionally Swift concepts through examples. Personally recommended.